# Form output not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple app for adding reviews to movies (using TMDb API). The problem is that when I try to save the review, I don't see it on the movie show page. This has happened to me with other apps - some field outputs not showing on the show page.

Controller

```
def show
  @movie = Tmdb::Movie.detail(params[:id])
   ...
  @movie_reviews = MovieReview.where(movie_id: params[:id])
end
```

Show

```
<% @movie_reviews.each do |movie_review| %>
  <%= movie_review.title %>
  <%= movie_review.content %>    
<% end %>
```

Form

```
<%= form_for :movie_review, url: movie_movie_reviews_path(params[:movie_id]) do |f| %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :content %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
</p>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `<%= f.text_area :cortent %>` typo?

Comment: Yes, I've changed it, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What is your form target action? The movie_movie_reviews_path(params[:movie_id])? And the action that renders the form?

Comment: @Xantar Try to add a movie review then `$ rails console`, `> MovieReview.last` to verify it's actually in the database.  If it exists in the database then you know the problem is isolated to displaying a movie review.

Comment: I tried with MovieReview.first and it shows on all pages (not just on the specific movie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you save, but you should have the @movie=Movie.find(..) and then @movie_review=@movie.movie_reviews.create(params)

Which means you probably need a hidden field in your form for the movie_id or assign it before rendering the form.

**Edit:**
You are passing the form action url as follows:

```
movie_movie_reviews_path(params[:movie_id])
```

Posting to the reviews index path is the correct action for `create`, but you still need to tell the controller what you are trying to say. So, you should just do:

```
movie_movie_reviews_path
```

and then, in your form, add the id of the movie for which the review will be:

```
<%= form_for...
<%= f.hidden_field :movie_id, :value => @movie.id %>
```

So, you will now have a param mapping the movie_id for the movie_review (@movie comes from the controller, remember?)

Finally, in your `create` action:

Either 
a) you permit :movie_id in your movie_review_params and do nothing more

```
def movie_review_params
  params.require(:movie_review).permit(:title, :content, :movie_id)
end
```

b) Or you don't touch your movie_review_params and instead of:

```
@movie_review = MovieReview.new(movie_review_params)
```

do

```
@movie_review = Movie.find(params[:movie_id]).movie_reviews.new(movie_review_params)
```

Comment: I did put hidden_field :movie_id, but it doesn't help. Also, I defined -movie and -movie_review. I'm using an API, so I'm just saving id.

Comment: movie_movie_reviews_path(params[:movie_id])

Comment: I mean, where does yhis param come from? Is this surely correct?

Comment: For starters, you define @movie in your before_action so you don't need redefine it in each action. Secondly, as I suspected, there is no place where you tell the controller that the review belongs to a specific movie. You are using strong params only allowing content and title, so you need to set the id for the Movie instance (for example @movie). I will write more in my answer.

Comment: It solved the issue. Thank you. Just a question - how can I redirect to show a review when a create it?
if @movie_review.save
 redirect_to (???)

Comment: As simple as: redirect_to @movie_review

Comment: I get - undefined method `movie_review_url'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you have nested resources. In that case maybe you should try redirect_to movie_movie_review_path(@movie_review)

Comment: Anyway, you can get a list of your available routes by running "rake routes" at your command prompt